# Merge between Active Directory membership provider & sqlprovider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, membership-provider

I have been asked to merge between the users of domain and the users of a web site in asp.net website
however when i set the default membership to one of them
ADMembershipProvider
or
SqlProvider
I can't access the other users

like if i have domain account while the membership is sqlpro it will not be able to access the website and vice versa

I need to make all the users of the domain and the original users of the website to be able to access their accounts

Comment: no that one is his comment not an answer, same is mine.

Comment: oh my gosh !!, I think you are smart, **thanks for comment this out**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple, just create your own MembershipProvider which internally uses both to perform user validation.

Something like:

```
    public override bool ValidateUser( string username, string password )
    {
        SqlMembershipProvider sql = new SqlMembershipProvider();

        NameValueCollection sqlparameters = new NameValueCollection();
        sqlparameters.Add("param", "value");

        sql.Initialize( "SqlProvider", sqlparameters );

        if ( sql.ValidateUser( username, password ) )
            return true;

        ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider ad = new ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider();
        NameValueCollection adparameters = new NameValueCollection();

        adparameters.Add( "param", "value" );

        ad.Initialize( "Ad", adparameters );
        if ( ad.ValidateUser( username, password ) )
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```